# MySQL Insert statement, If a specified inserted row has a column value 0, do not insert?

Tags: mysql

I am just wondering if it is possible to have this check in MySQL itself? If the Column (`Value`) has a incoming inserted value of 0, Do not insert.

For Example:

```
Insert Into `Schema`.`Table` (`ID`,`Name`,`Value`) values (1,'John',0);
Insert Into `Schema`.`Table` (`ID`,`Name`,`Value`) values (2,'Henry',2);
Insert Into `Schema`.`Table` (`ID`,`Name`,`Value`) values (3,'Ryan',5);
```

OR

```
Insert Into `Schema`.`Table` (`ID`,`Name`,`Value`) 
values (1,'John',0),(2,'Henry',2),(3,'Ryan',5);
```

Result:

```
+----+-------+------+
| ID | Name  | Value|
+----+-------+------+
| 2  | Henry |   2  |
+----+-------+------+
| 3  | Ryan  |   5  |
+----+-------+------+
```

Comment: You would likely need to use a trigger. It would likely be better to offload this check to your application side if possible.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I think I would stick with check before the insert.

Comment: If negative values are also not allowed, you can define your column as `UNSIGNED INT`. Although for 0 value, you will still have to handle it in your application code

Answer (score 0):

You could use CHECK Value > 0, when you created the following table.

Comment: `CHECK` does not work in MySQL. MySQL parser allows it in syntax, but does not consider it.